# Why does my program not populate the array with pixel values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ioctl, fcntl

I'm working with a Lepton Thermal Camera Breakout Board and trying to read in pixel values using this simple python program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pylepton import Lepton

with Lepton("/dev/spidev0.0") as l:
     a,_ = l.capture()

cv2.normalize(a, a, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) #extend contrast
np.right_shift(a, 8, a) #fit data into 8 bits
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", np.uint8(a)) #write it
```

The program calls the `capture()` method which is located in a file called [Lepton.py](https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton/blob/master/pylepton/Lepton.py) which I got from GitHub. The program is supposed to take input from the thermal camera store it to an array which it then returns along with a "frame ID". However, it is currently just returning an empty array with nothing that contains nothing but 0.

I can't figure out why this would happen. The `capture.py` method inside of Lepton.py calls another method called `capture_segment()` which contains a call to `ioctl` but at that point I can't understand what the program is doing.

Where are the actual values being read in? Is there a way to cut down on the amount of code so that I can just read in the values and store them directly?

EDIT: The camera is directly plugged into a Raspberry Pi and this python program is the only thing I'm running.

Comment: Do you have any other software talking to the camera? Are you sure it's working and is set up correctly?

Comment: Have you tried the debug_print=True option, for some hints?

Comment: The camera is plugged into a Raspberry Pi and this is the only program that I am running. Also, I'm sure my wiring is correct because I used another program that was provided by the manufacturer and it was able to take a picture so I know that values are being sent to the Pi.

Comment: @Benjamin yup it just tells me that everything is 0s basically. Originally I also had `retry_reset = True` and it would get stuck in an loop because all the frames being returned had just 0 in them. I just need to find where the program is actually supposed to reading in values so that I can see if anything is coming in.